# How do I use a CakePHP third party library function?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to call a third party library function in CakePHP from a controller file.

I have this in my controller file:

```
public function index() {
    App::import('vendor', 'simple-html-dom.php');
    App::import('vendor', 'utils.php');

    set_time_limit(0);

    $html = file_get_html("google.com");
    ...
}
```

I also have in `app/vendor` both `simple-html-dom.php` and `utils.php` files.

`file_get_html` is a public function in `simple-html-dom.php` (and it doesn't belong to any class).  I end up with this error:

> ```
> Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html()
> ```

I have been trying to search for how to solve this, but I have not found an answer.

Comment: Try to place 3rd party libraries in webroot. And also use firebug to see the files included.

Comment: webroot? they belong in "Vendor"

Answer (score 2):

I got mine working. Try this,

```
App::import('Vendor', 'simple_html_dom', array('file'=>'simple_html_dom.php'));

$html = file_get_html("google.com");
```

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why that fixes the problem?  I don't [claim to] know PHP, so I'm not sure why this would be an ideal solution, just by looking at it.

Comment: TBH I don't know neither. I'm just did try and error from Dipesh answer and got it works. That's the only time I'm doing project in Cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function index() {
    App::import('vendor', 'simple-html-dom.php');
    App::import('vendor', 'utils.php');

    set_time_limit(0);
    $SimpleHtmlDom = new SimpleHtmlDom(); // create object for html dom
    $html = $SimpleHtmlDom->file_get_html("google.com");
}
```

Make sure `simple-html-dom.php` file contain class then you need to `create object` of that `class` after loading `vendor`.

because to access `methods` and `property` of class you need to create `object` of that class.

You can also access `method` with in same class using `Self::file_get_html();` but this is for inside `class declaration`.

**More help**

```
App::import('Vendor', 'example', array('file' => 'Example.php'));
$example = new Example();
```

in above code i am including vendor file.

**explanation**

Above code will load `Example.php` file which is inside `vendors/example` directory.

In your case your `vendor` file is not properly loaded that's why you are getting `class not found` error.

Comment: Thank you.  But the file_get_html function itself is not inside any classes.

Comment: And I tried just simply wrapping that function and two other functions that weren't in a class, in a class, that I called SimpleHtmlDomHelper.  Then I tried using: $SimpleHtmlDom = new  SimpleHtmlDomHelper(); $html = $SimpleHtmlDom->file_get_html("google.com"); But I got "Class 'SimpleHtmlDomHelper' not found".  It's as if simple_html_dom.php is not being included at all.

Comment: @user1296259 i have updated answer please have a look i m sure that will solve it.